# Установка PyQt5 на Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, pyqt5, sip

Доброго времени суток. Такая проблема: не устанавливается SIP на Windows 10. Выдает такую ошибку:

```
C:\Windows\system32>pip3 install PyQt5
Collecting PyQt5
Using cached PyQt5-5.9.2-5.9.3-cp35.cp36.cp37-none-win_amd64.whl
Collecting sip<4.20,>=4.19.4 (from PyQt5)
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sip<4.20,>=4.19.4
(from PyQt5) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for sip<4.20,>=4.19.4 (from PyQt5)
```

Может кто-нибудь знает как решить проблему?

Comment: 1) версия питона 2) пробовали обновить sip?

Comment: @gil9red 1) Python 3.7 2) я как раз sip и не могу установить

Comment: а что пишет при установке sip?

Comment: @gil9red Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sip (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for sip

Comment: попробуйте на 3.6 поставить

Comment: @gil9red на 3.6 тоже не ставится, та же ошибка

Comment: попробуйте анаконду https://www.anaconda.com